# Different results using same function from different libraries

Tags: c++, cmath

Here is some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int a, b;
    long long int c;

    cin >> a >> b;

    c = abs(a) + abs(b);
    cout << c;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Which supposed to return `1000000000000000002` when I input `1000000000000000000` and `2`.

If I try to do it with `cmath` it will return `1000000000000000000`, but if I use `cstdlib` it will return `1000000000000000002`. Why is that even happening?

Also considering that I'm using cmath, shouldn't it work even more proper?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 64bit, Eclipse Platform.

Comment: @Ron that's not the question. Also when I remove both there's an error. `‘abs’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Did you compile in C++11 mode? (Not my downvote btw, before you jump to conclusions.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen That's what Eclipse says. `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d" -MT"src/Test.d" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp"`

Comment: Oops, nevermind, I was wrong. The integer `abs` functions only got added to `<cmath>` in C++17, so you currently do need to include `<cstdlib>` as the answer explains. *Mea culpa.*

Comment: @BaummitAugen can you add this as an answer. It's correct.
http://i.imgur.com/dCmboiP.png

Comment: @BaummitAugen This works as intended in VC++ 2013 and [Linux](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22fad79e60b7bd96) without the above headers. Not your culpa.

Comment: @Ron without -std=c++11 or whatever flag, I'm getting this error. `Test.cpp:11:11: error: ‘abs’ was not declared in this scope` c99 invalid then. :p Today I learned. But, if I add the flag it works fine.

Comment: @Ron This is an implementation specific "coincidence", too. The standard library headers are allowed to include other headers, but `<iostream>` does not guarantee to give you `std::abs`, you should include the correct header (in this case `<cstdlib>`) anyways.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ah right you are. I was overseeing the fact that the OP's compiler didn't support the C++ 11 standard. I stand corrected.

Comment: if turn-on compiler warnings life will be simpler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cmath version is a [float one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/). So when you only have that one, you actually do the computation on floats and convert back into a `long long` at the end. Float precision not being enough to hold 18 digits, the +2 simply gets lost.

The cstdlib version is a [integer one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/). Which gives the expected result.

As pointed out in the comments, in C++11, cmath also defines a version of `abs` that takes integers. However, *“these overloads effectively cast x to a double before calculations (defined for T being any integral type)”*.

I believe your compiler should give you a warning for the conversions if you use `-Wall -Wextra` or similar flags while only inclulding cmath.

Comment: You're right, but don't guess: look it up. Also, the code in the question uses `long long`, so the conversation at the end is to `long long`, not to `long`.

Comment: @PeteBecker> the cstdlib version defines overloads for `int`, `long int` (from c++98) and `long long int` (from c++11). The cmath version defines overloads for `float`, `double`, `long double`.

Comment: And, finally, it's not `float` precision here, it's `double`. `float` (when it's IEEE-754, which is typical) holds 6-9 digits; `double` holds 15-17.

Comment: Yes, those are the overloads. Now you can remove the "Quick guess:" from the top of your answer. <g>

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman That's an implementation specific "coincidence" (pre C++17). As I said, I messed up, it should indeed be `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: @spectras I'm accepting this as the answer. Thank you. Also all the other people for their input to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using g++, try to compile both versions with `-Wconversion` (or `-Wfloat-conversion`).

Note that the `<cmath>` version generates a warning:

> main.cpp:14:7: **warning**: conversion to ‘long long int’ from ‘__gnu_cxx::__enable_if::__type {aka double}’ **may alter its value** [-Wfloat-conversion]
>        c = abs(a) + abs(b);

While the `<cstdlib>`version compiles without warnings.

That is because, in [`<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath), `abs()` is defined as<sup>1</sup>:

```
float abs(float);
double abs(double);
long double abs(long double);
```

While in [`<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) it is defined as<sup>1</sup>:

```
int abs(int);
long abs(long);
long long abs(long long);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The integer versions of `abs()` are defined in `<cmath>` since C++17.